# for loop break statment

Tags: python, for-loop, break

```py
city_flight = input("London, Edinburgh, Liverpool, Manchester"'\t').lower()    
for city in city_flight:
        if city != "London" and city != "Edinburgh" and city != "Liverpool" and city != "Manchester":
            print("Enter the city properly")
        break
        num_nights = int(input("How many nights prefer to stay?" '\t'))
        rental_days = int(input("How many days rent a car?" '\t'))
```

I have tried so many times and stuck break statement not working, I want if the condition is not met go back to the first line of code. so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a `for` loop over `city_flight` is just iterating over the individual characters in the string -- instead, use a `while True` loop that includes the thing that you want to repeat (the `input()` call), and `break` it when the input is correct:

```
while True:
    city = input("London, Edinburgh, Liverpool, Manchester\t").lower()    
    if city in {"london", "edinburgh", "liverpool", "manchester"}:
        break  # end loop and continue to num_nights etc
    print("Enter the city properly")  # repeat the loop

num_nights = int(input("How many nights prefer to stay?\t"))
rental_days = int(input("How many days rent a car?\t"))
```

You can also eliminate some duplication by putting the cities in a list and using that for both your `input` text and the validation, e.g.:

```
cities = ["London", "Edinburgh", "Liverpool", "Manchester"]
while True:
    city = input(", ".join(cities) + "\t").title()
    if city in cities:
        break
    # etc
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
city_flight = input("London, Edinburgh, Liverpool, Manchester"'\t').lower()
#Change for loop to a while loop
#while the city is not one of the 4 cities, keep asking the user
#The cities in the last are in lower case because you did .lower() on the input
while city_flight not in ["london", "edinburgh", "liverpool", "manchester"]:
    print("Enter the city properly")
    city_flight = input("London, Edinburgh, Liverpool, Manchester"'\t').lower()
#Once city_flight is a correct city, the below lines execute
num_nights = int(input("How many nights prefer to stay?" '\t'))
rental_days = int(input("How many days rent a car?" '\t'))
```